# Long tabularx, problem with spacing using setspace

Tags: tabularx, setspace, ltablex

I am using `setspace` to control the spacing of my text but I don't want it to affect my tables. Now I run into a problem when trying to have a table that spans over multiple pages because the spacing isn't corrected anymore. Any advice on how to fix that?

Below you find a MWE.

Thank you.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}\keepXColumns

\usepackage{setspace} 
\setstretch{1.3} 

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]    
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ l X }
    \caption{This is a normal table and it is displyed correctly with the appropriate line spacing.} \\
        \toprule
        Header 1 & Header 2 \\
        \midrule 
        foo & Occaecati et sed quo et aut nostrum esse. Eos ratione tenetur pariatur impedit magnam quam consequatur. Quia dolores reiciendis sit autem mollitia... \\
        foo & bar \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ l X }
    \caption{The spacing of this table is off. But I need it to go over multiple pages.} \\
        \toprule
        Header 1 & Header 2 \\
        \midrule 
        foo & Occaecati et sed quo et aut nostrum esse. Eos ratione tenetur pariatur impedit magnam quam consequatur. Quia dolores reiciendis sit autem mollitia... \\
        foo & bar \\
        foo & bar \\
        foo & bar \\
        foo & bar \\
        foo & bar \\
        foo & bar \\
        foo & bar \\
        foo & bar \\
        foo & bar \\
        foo & bar \\
        foo & bar \\
        foo & bar \\
        foo & bar \\
        foo & bar \\
        foo & bar \\
        foo & bar \\
        foo & bar \\
        \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wrap the second table in `\begingroup\setstretch{1}  ... \endgroup`, this has presumably been added to the `table` env, but that is not being used in the second table.

Comment: Thank you that worked :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a error in code that was solved in the comments.

Comment: @Sveinung that is not an error in the code, I'll add an answer shortly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
\begingroup
\setstretch{1}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ l X }
...
\end{tabularx}
\endgroup
```

This construction is presumably added to the `table` env, but is obviously not added to the table itself thus the need to manually add it.